# CSS: in td (table) make all words from the new line

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have such code:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Text</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Long Long cell content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Long Long cell content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and style:

```
table{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t5rxtweo/

now it looks so on big resolution:

[image]

but on small:

[image]

and and small i wanna so:

[image]

can i do it with pure css?

Comment: What do you want? I guess your question needs some formatting.

Comment: @Paran0a on small resolution all words in td must be on new line

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Do you want all the words on the same line? If so, you have my answer. Or, if you need each word to be on different lines, like the small one, just reduce the width to 0.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, sorry, but in question: `make all words from the new line`!!! not on the same line!

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense are you wanting a word per line in small screens? is that what you are saying? And what constitutes a small screen?

Comment: @Pete
small screen? it doesn't matter, it could be 768px width, 1440px width etc.
all words in td from new line, what is unclear? All was described in question

Comment: @Pete answer from `Paran0a` is good!

Comment: @brabertaser1992 in that case I would make your `wordspacing` match your `max-width` all words from new line is very bad english from new line suggest that you are wanting to get words from a new line somewhere, it should be on a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you define "small resolutions"?

Anyway here's a demo that you can play with.

https://jsfiddle.net/t5rxtweo/1/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    td {
        word-spacing: 9999999px;
    }
}

<table>
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Text</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Long Long cell content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Long Long cell content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```